# How to make an access database where both users with and without an ID number can make a transaction

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to create an access 2007 database that allows staff that already have ID numbers to make a transaction and also other guest users who do not have ID number make a transaction. What is the best way todo this in access? A transaction involves taking an item out of inventory. Therefore if one a user (staff or external) has an item out of inventory then no other users can get a hold of that item. Thanks, Any Ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: How does the user with an ID make the transaction at the moment? What exactly is the problem? Indexes? Tracking guests?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had a table of users with a primary key then I would just setup a “Guest” user in this table. Again assuming that your inventory table has a filed called “BookOutBy” then you would just enter this guest users ID in that field and the normal user ID for everyone else.

Lots of assumptions but then you did not give us many specifics to go on!